# Custom Animation Object for Transition in Android?

Tags: android, animation, transition

I want to override the default activity transition in Android with something a bit fancier. What I want to do can't be done with the XML set that one would typically use, so I can't use `overridePendingTransition` because it only accepts integer references to XML-based animation resources.

What I'd like to do instead is create my own object that inherits from `Animation` and overrides the `getTransformation` and `applyTransformation` methods to do my own thing. This much I can do, but I can't seem to find a way to tie this new animation object into the transition. Is there a method like `overridePendingTransition` that accepts an Animation object? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the job is done by the `WindowManagerService`, which calls `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation`. `AnimationUtils` only loads animation sets from xml resources, so it's not possible to use a customized Animation object.

Hope someone would propose a patch to AOSP that adds support to customized Animation object...

Comment: That's the impression I got overall, thank you for clearing it up with specifics. And yes, it would be nice if support for custom Animation objects was patched in!