# How can I use a Java animation to transition between Activities

Tags: android, animation

In my Android app, I've written a custom Animation subclass to handle some of my view transitions.  I want to use the same animation for the transition between Activities in my app.  How can I use my Animation subclass for the Activity transition?

I'm aware of calling `overridePendingTransition()`, but that won't work in this case:

1. My animations are not in XML resources, and
2. It's not possible to represent them with just the supported tags in `AnimationUtils`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appears that it is not currently possible:  [Custom Animation Object for Transition in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001440/custom-animation-object-for-transition-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to combine two or more activities into one and then use ViewFlipper, where you can set fancy animations on flipped views.